my model smooths out when exporting as stl
I like what I see (Middle and right images) when in blender. Everything has been triangulated and modifiers applied. What else can i do to make the image be the right two not the left one. (left one is the exported stl)
Thanks

Try increasing the resolution. Add more geometry subdivide it more.
